# excluding number of groups in mat table pagination

Tags: angular-material, pagination, grouping, mat-table

I'm using mat table to display data with row grouping. I'm following this example for implementing row grouping https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-mat-table-row-grouping-f1kwty?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts this solution works fine for row grouping however, when i added the pagination i came across the following problem.

I have row grouping to group items in the mat table and pagination so if I have 10 items divided in two groups of 5 items each. The pagination will show total 12 items because of the two groups.
Actual Results:
Wrong items count per page.
Expected Results:
Count the actual items listed. Don't count the group as if they were items too.